# Error al intentar instalar dotnet ef de manera global en visual studio code

Tags: entity-framework-core, c#-8.0

Al intentar instalar ef con el siguiente comando: dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef

Obtengo la siguiente salida en consola:

**La asignación de origen del paquete está habilitada, pero no se encontró ningún origen en el id. de paquete especificado: dotnet-ef**

Ojo: Tengo instalados los nugets correspondientes de EntityFrameWork.